# Read line by line and saving matching column to a new document python - Beginne

Tags: python, dataset, bigdata, saving-data

I need to say that I am a beginner at coding and maybe this can be easy if you are more experienced but I couldn't find any problem similar to mine so I am sending here.

I have a huge document (~40 GB) that is a table content. This file is divided in columns with many blank spaces between them. Also, I have a list in another document (a very small one) where I have some names that is also contained in the huge document. If my code find lines that in this column the name matches with one of the names I have on the list, then I want to append everyline to another list to use only this specific ones:

So I created the following code on spider:

```
import pandas as pd 
station_list = pd.read_fwf(r"D:\Não apagar arquivos importantes\Desktop\Para dados grandes\Lisn.txt", header = None, skiprows = 1)



saved=[]
with open (r"D:\Não apagar arquivos importantes\Downloads\Out 2016\los_20161015.001.h5.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        lst=line.split()
        sline=" ".join(lst)
        tag=lst[12]
        if tag in station_list:
            saved.append(sline)
```

So, when I run it, it reads line by line very quickly but.. Even though most of the names I have on the file station_list are inside the column on f, it do not save the slines to my new saved list.

What can it be?? Does anybody have a suggestion? Is there any more effective way to use big files?

[Image of the variables I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIi3U.jpg)
Thank you

Comment: Is the check  `if tag in station_list:` passing?

Comment: Is there anyway to check if it is passing?

Comment: Add a print and see if it happens.

Comment: Ok I will add a print to check

Comment: Thank you very much, with your suggestion I realized this is not working. I wrote a random name of the station I wanted and then it worked. Now I will have to convert my df station_list to a list of strings in order to make it work